# Docx4J command line to convert doc/docx files to html

Tags: java, docx4j

I have been trying to convert doc/docx files to html, the best bet I found is [docx4j](http://dev.plutext.org/trac/docx4j). 
Can anyone please help me with a straight command line to do this job.

I tried:

```
java -cp docx4j.jar:log4j-1.2.15.jar org.docx4j.samples.CreateHtml [input.docx]
```

In response I would expect HTML output (either to the console or a file).

Comment: This question makes sufficient sense imho.  But since it looks like it is about to get closed, if someone wants to re-word/ask it again, I'll provide an up to date answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to ax for providing line of thought, but that command gave Class missing error so all was needed to include other jar files in path.

```
java -cp docx4j-2.6.0.jar:log4j-1.2.15.jar:xalan-2.7.1.jar:serializer-2.7.1.jar:xml-apis-1.3.04.jar:commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:commons-lang-2.4.jar:commons-io-1.3.1.jar:commons-codec-1.3.jar:xmlgraphics-commons-1.4.jar org.docx4j.samples.CreateHtml input.doc
```

Comment: after begging for answer, it would be nice to edit ax's answer and accept it, since he gave you proper command!

Answer (score 6):

looking at http://dev.plutext.org/svn/docx4j/trunk/docx4j/docs/Docx4j_GettingStarted.html and the [samples dir](http://dev.plutext.org/svn/docx4j/trunk/docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/), i would think that

```
java -cp docx4j.jar:log4j-1.2.15.jar org.docx4j.samples.CreateHtml [input.docx]
```

should work. note the following from the *Getting Started* > *Command Line Samples* section:

> If there are any images in the docx, you'd also need:
>
> ```
> xmlgraphics-commons-1.4.jar
> commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
> ```
>
> on your classpath.

Comment: Thanks ax it helped, but gave some class missing error. I am posting correct command line below.

Comment: you could just edit my answer and add the missing dependencies, so as to avoid duplicate answers.

Comment: I'm getting a `Could not find or load main class org.docx4j.samples.CreateHtml` error. Does docx4j have to be installed other than being in directory you're executing from?